# Fetch API can't find controller in asp .net core web api application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, fetch

I'm attempting to use fetch api to load data from my asp .net core web api application to my react component. But I'm very confused that when I use the example `await fetch('weatherforecast')` in `FetchData` component to call `WeatherForecastController`. It works. I did a debugging in the example code, the function in `WeatherForecastController` is well reached, but if I use this idea in my project, it does not work, my function in debugging is not reached. Could someone explain the usage of fetch api in my case?

The controller class

```html
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<T> Get()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

My react component

```html
const response = await fetch('Hello');
```

In program.cs (I'm using .net 6)

```html
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "MY API", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY APP v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I found something interesting in `setupProxy`

```html
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const context = [
    '/weatherforecast',
    '/controllerName1',
    '/controllerName2',
];

module.exports = function (app) {
    const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
        target: 'https://localhost:5001',
        secure: false
    });

    app.use(appProxy);
};
```

The default `weatherforecast` controller works, de route is correct via debugging. But if I try it in another controller, it does not work. Can someone explain it pls?

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET at all, but you said `[Route("[controller]")]` and `fetch('Hello');` Shouldn't those names match?

Comment: Yes, they should match. This mechanism works in the example code, but does not work for me. I don't know why.

Comment: If they should match, why have you written them so they don't? Does making them match fix the problem?

Comment: I don't understand your meaning very well. But the point is that I want to figure out how does this mechanism work. As others said, I have the same feeling that it is something to do with route prefix setup, but I don't know where specifically.

Comment: You named your route `controller`! You are asking the server for something named `Hello`!

Comment: do you undetstand the difference between [Route("[controller]")] and [Route("controller")]

Comment: No, I literally started this comment thread by saying "I don't know ASP.NET at all".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a controller by adding to the **setupProxy** and added a controller to it.

```
const context = [
    '/weatherforecast',
    '/hello'
];
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you check Startup.cs? May be you have route prefix setup there. like `api`. So in that case your url would be `/api/hello`
Or configure  [swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) that will tell exact route and also give you option to try your API

Comment: But in example code `fetch('weatherforecase')` and the controller is reached when I use the same idea in my project. It did not work.

Comment: now can run swagger and check the API URL? You can access swagger at https://localhost:xxxx/swagger

Comment: I checked swagger at localhost:xxxxx/swagger. It shows a blank page. Btw, I posted the entire program class for clarity.